# how to create folders from an XML file (powershell)

Tags: xml, powershell

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENkMx.png)I want to create a program which basically creates a folder automatically right after running the program And the title of the folders are stored in a XML file.

They are all subfolders, so starting with the first one, the second folder is inside the first, the third folder inside the second folder, which is in the first etc.

```
Folder names: 
-Customer
   -Location
      -productionline
         -serialnumber
            -system
```

however, i have absolutely no clue how to write that in powershell (actually never used that before), especially how to use something out of an xml file...
something with

`New-Item -Path $newDirectory -ItemType Directory` i guess

Comment: you could start with parsing xml `https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-parse-xml/` and then use `New-Item` Cmdlet

Comment: all right, I am gonna try that out, it will take some time, but thanks in the meantime

Comment: Can you post a sample XML document?

Comment: Hey, I cant post a file, so a made a screenshot, but I couldnt post that either, so a link in the question above.

Comment: That's a screenshot of a spreadsheet application. Are you perhaps confusing CSV and XML?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] (a **sanitized** data sample, of course).

Comment: Hey, I dont really care what it should be, I dont mind whether it is a csv file, xml or xlm file. What suits better? Does anyone has a sample for me?